# ATmega 2560, additional software serial port advice

Tags: arduino, serial, atmega, software

I am trying to make a project with an ATmega 2560 microcontroller. I need 5 UARTs, but the microcintroller has only 4 of them. I want to connect 4 of them to RS485 and 1 additional software serial to RS485 as shown below.

In short, how can I configure a pin of 2560 as software serial which will connect to a RS485 device.  I am allowed to use only one ATmega 2560.

[image]

Comment: Given the MCU can only reasonably talk to one device at a time, why not just combine the RS485 devices onto the same bus?

Comment: As it stands the question seems to be purely software rather than electrical design, so you'd probably be better off asking to have the question migrated to Arduino.SE

Comment: Why can't you use a different processor, or add a second processor? Is this a school project?

Comment: You can also add an external UART (if you can still find one).

Comment: RS485 is a bus. why do you need 5 of them? put all devices on one bus

Answer (score 0):

A "software serial" is not a configuration, but means that you'll be *bit-banging* out your serial protocol: whereas in your hardware UARTs, you simply write some data to a register to transmit, and read the received data from a register, here you'll need to write software to pull up a pin, make the system wait for a defined time, pull down a pin... to transmit bits. Receiving requires you to sample an external pin.

This is usually not feasible when your MCU might be occupied with something else - like handling the data from the four other UARTs! So, your receive sampling will have to happen in timer interrupts, which I hope you have enough of.

Probably, there is some existing implementation for a software serial for the RTOS you're using (you really want to use an RTOS here; having different data handling tasks with different priorities is exactly what becomes easier and safer when you use an RTOS).